# How to replace characters in string of variable within a FOR loop?

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file called NonProd.txt containing a server name on each line, i.e.

```
c123abc
c234abc
c345abc
cfcd123
etc.
```

I also have a batch file (given below) which reads each line from the text file, extracts 3 characters from each line, and holds that value in variable. I then want to use the variable to replace the `XXX` characters in the `mypath` variable.

The code below works in reading the text file, extracting the server names and extracting the 3 characters it needs, but I cannot get the string substitution to work, i.e. replace `XXX` in `mypath` with the 3 characters extracted.

Can anyone advise?

```
@echo off

SET mypath=C:\XXX\SYS\exe\folder\folder\

FOR /F %%X IN (NonProd.txt) DO (
  echo ServerName = %%X
  Call Set "SID=%%X"
  Call Set "SID=%%SID:~1,3%%"
  Call Echo SID = %%SID%%

  ECHO mypath = %mypath%

  CALL set mypath=%mypath:XXX=%SID%%

  ECHO newpath = %mypath%
  ECHO.
)

@echo Completed.
pause
```

Comment: You need DelayedExpansion: `CALL set mypath=%%mypath:XXX=!SID!%%` and also `call ECHO newpath = %%mypath%%`

Comment: This may also work without DelayedExpansion (untested)= `CALL CALL set mypath=%%%%mypath:XXX=%%SID%%%%%%`

Answer (score 2):

I didn't understand why you use `call` and not `enabledelayedexpansion`. Anyway, see the following code:

```vb
@echo off
cls
setlocal
(
echo c123abc
echo c234abc
echo c345abc
echo cfcd123
)>%temp%\_file.tmp

set mypath=c:\xxx\sys\exe\folder\folder\
echo:
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%temp%\_file.tmp) do (
    set "sid=%%a"
    rem :: set "sid=!sid:~1,3!"
    set mypath=%mypath:xxx=!sid:~1,3!%
    echo sid: !sid!, servername: !sid:~1,3!, newpath: !mypath!
)
endlocal
echo Completed.
exit /b 0
```

output:

> sid: c123abc, servername: 123, newpath: c:\123\sys\exe\folder\folder\
>   sid: c234abc, servername: 234, newpath: c:\234\sys\exe\folder\folder\
>   sid: c345abc, servername: 345, newpath: c:\345\sys\exe\folder\folder\
>   sid: cfcd123, servername: fcd, newpath: c:\fcd\sys\exe\folder\folder\
>   Completed.

Answer (score 1):

The code with using delayed expansion as suggested by [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "mypath=C:\XXX\SYS\exe\folder\folder\"

for /F %%X IN (NonProd.txt) do (
  echo ServerName = %%X
  set "SID=%%X"
  set "SID=!SID:~1,3!"
  echo SID = !SID!

  set newpath=%mypath:XXX=!SID!%

  echo newpath = !newpath!
  echo.
)

echo Completed.
endlocal
pause
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

`if /?` is included in this list although **IF** is not used in code as help of command **IF** explains *delayed expansion* on examples which often must be used in any block defined with `(` ... `)`.